# Cannot create a file when that file already exists. localhost vs published project

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm getting the "Cannot create a file when that file already exists" error when I try to do File.Move() when using a published version of my ASP.net project (hosted on IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2).

Now I try to run my project locally with Visual Studio (F5) it works with no issues.

The file both projects are accessing are stored over a local network.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
    btnClick(..)
    {
           Move("\\192.168.10.10\folder2\test.pdf", "\\192.168.10.10\folder2\test(1).pdf");
    }

    public static void Move(string filename, string destname)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(destname));
        System.IO.File.Move(filename, destname);
    }
```

Comment: If you're getting that error, then `destname` already exists.  Further, since this code can throw that exception you should be checking whether the file already exists and handling that accordingly.

Comment: I'm just a bit confused as to why it works when running it locally as opposed to publishing it to an IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

I have had an issue like this before, and it was a Windows security problem. Ensure the share and/or folder have the correct permissions set for the account your application is using.